# Replacing a | delimiter with a \r\n but keeping the text in the same column and cell

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

This was originally marked as a duplicate but the answer provided there was way off the mark.

I have a c# app that reads a text file and looks for `^` characters and replaces them with `\t`. It also looks for `|` characters and attempts to replace them with `\r\n`.

This .txt file should then be copied into a spreadsheet. The problem is that when the app replaces `|` it places the data into the first cell of a new row. I want it kept in the same cell/order it was originally with words separated by `|` forming sort of a vertical list within that single sell (a bit like a alt+Enter in Excel).

For example the input is:

```
This^is^testing^to^see|if|it|works
```

The output I need is:

```
This    is    testing    to    see 
                               if
                               it
                               works
```

Instead I get:

```
This    is    testing    to    see 
if
it
works
```

I am currently using:

```
 File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text).Replace("|", "\r\n"));
 File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text).Replace("^", "\t"));
```

Button Click Code: (note that textbox1.text contains the file path and file name gained via OpenFileDialog).

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text).Replace("^", "\t"));
        File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text).Replace("|", "\r\n"));
        var input = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("File Editing Underway - Please give it a few seconds");
}
```

Where am I slipping up?

The closure of this question was of no help. `\r\n` does the same thing.
I need the replacement of the `|` delimiter to keep the information in the same cell. As you can see it the above example it is moving it a row down into the A (first) column thanks to the `\n` I assume.

Comment: Without code it's almost impossible to help with this

Comment: IS File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text).Replace("|", "\r\n"));
 File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text).Replace("^", "\t")); not enough?

Comment: If that's the extent of the code then the problem is that you aren't processing the file correctly.  How would the values on their own lines align with the position of the last tab?  You need to parse the file line by line and keep a track of which column your newline values belong on.

Comment: I get what you mean and what I am doing is a simple find and replace.  The problem is I don't know how to parse the file.  The raw file is an output text file delimited by ^ which represents a new column and | which represents a alt+enter in a singular cell.  In the end it is a spreadsheet.

Comment: I think you have to make sure Excel treats `see\r\nif\r\nit\r\nworks` as a cell value by wrapping it in double quotes, i.e. `"see\r\nif\r\nit\r\nworks"`. But this will require something more complex than `Replace()`.

Comment: Are you trying to write to CSV or XLSX?

Comment: Ideally xlsx.  Once the input text is modified (delimiters removed) I will be outputting it to the xlsx format.

Comment: Aligning perfectly is not that easy. depending on font in a particular workbook, the text can move ahead of back....

Answer (score 0):

If you're saving this file as a CSV, you can do this-

wrap each cell text block with double quotes `"`, so each like would look like this:

`"cell 1"\t"cell 2"\t"cell 3 line1\r\ncell 3 line 2"`

and then the CSV reader (or excel) would not break multi-line cells.

(This is part of CSV format, so it should be supported by most CSV readers)

As for implementation, here's a way:

```cs
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
fileContent = "\"" + fileContent.Replace("^", "\",\"") + "\"";
fileContent = fileContent.Replace("|", "\r\n");
File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, fileContent)
```

Please let me know if it solves it, or if some adjustments are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It still seems to have put "if it works" in row 2, 3 and 4 of the A column when they should go underneath each other in row 1 of E column.

Comment: I just tested this exact same code on a file with this content: This^is^testing^to^see|if|it|works and then opened in excel, and it seems just fine, the last cell E1 has 4 lines of "see if it works" (one word in each line)

Comment: Make sure you save the file as CSV